# Grouping and Coloring Clustered Bar Charts in BI

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization

I have a chart where I am comparing Male and Female values in each state.

[image]

How do I:

1. Combine the X-axis labels have one state per set of bars e.g. "GA" instead of "Male GA" "Female GA"
2. I had to go in and change 50 individual bars from blue to pink.  Is there a way construct this so that all the Male data is controlled in one place and and the Female in another so I don't have to make 50 changes each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put state in X axis, as you did, but then put gender in Legend.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly.  However, I had to remove sex from the axis as well.  So Legend: sex, Value: sex, Axis: state

Comment: That's right, perhaps I want clear on that